# Spring Boot 2 Security - can't seem to allow request to Login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security for the first time with a Spring Boot application. It's the one part of Spring I've never worked with before. I've got most things configured properly to authenticate a user, generate a JWT, and then validate that JWT on subsequent requests. My problem, though, is I can't seem to login. Every time I send the login request I get an error from my security filter. I've checked the configuration over and over again against examples I've found on the web, and I believe I've excluded my login path from authentication.

This is a project using Kotlin, by the way.

Anyway, here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig (
        private val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http?.let {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

            http.apply(JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder(12)
    }
}
```

And this is the JwtTokenFilterConfigurer:

```
class JwtTokenFilterConfigurer (
        private val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http?.let {
            val jwtFilter = JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider)
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my JwtTokenFilter:

```
class JwtTokenFilter (
        private val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(req)
        token?.let {
            try {
                if (!jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                    throw ApiUnauthorizedException("User is unauthorized")
                }
                val auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token)
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = auth
                chain.doFilter(req, resp)
                return
            }
            catch (ex: Exception) {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
                throw ex
            }
        }

        throw ApiUnauthorizedException("User is unauthorized")
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the ant matchers are set properly to allow login requests through without authenticating them. The full URL to login to the API is `POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login`.

Comment: Do you see anything in logs? Try enabling logs using `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`

Comment: Why are you not using the buildt in jwt filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a login path in the configuration:

```
...
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/api/auth/login")
...
```

I'm assuming you have configured a view/controller. Something simple like this:

```
...
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/api/auth/login");
    ...
```

Or a proper controller.

Comment: I'm doing a rest API so no views. That API endpoint simply takes a JSON payload with the credentials and authenticates them.

Comment: You're probably following a tutorial already, but this site always have good solutions for spring related features [link](https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security). It has a entire series dedicated to a rest api authentication.